# Open channel on ssh Server

Tags: java, apache, shell, sshd

How can I open a 'shell' channel to a connected ssh client using apache sshd from sshserver. [RFC 4254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-5.1) mentions

`When either side wishes to open a new channel, it allocates a local number for the channel`

which means the server can also open a channel to client.

But I do not see any API on `org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession`..? Am I missing something..? My requirement is to asynchronously send messages to sshclient from sshserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSH2 protocol was designed to be extensible in case there will be some use case for something like this. But it was not yet the case and there are not channels that could be initiated from the server side.

Therefore even if there would be such request, it would be invalid in most of the clients, as you can see when you search through the [OpenSSH code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN):

- `packet_start(SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN);` creates a new channel from client side
- `dispatch_set(SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN, &server_input_channel_open);` assigns handler for this message in server.

There is nothing like that the other way round so it would be ignored or cause a error.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje.  So, does that mean OpenSSH is not compliant with the RFC then.. ? If asynchronous messaging from server is not supported, Is it a good idea to keep a channel opened from client dedicated for this purpose...? What do you suggest for an optimised solution..?

Comment: No. The RFC talks broadly about possibilities, bot other RFC specify the channel types. And none of them makes sense to open from server from usability nor security point of view.

Comment: Is it a good idea to keep a channel opened from client dedicated for this purpose...?

Comment: If it will solve the problem for you, then it is an option.

Comment: Hopefully it solves, I'll try that out. Thanks for your time @Jakuje.